# Set timeout for PLSQL block or query inside procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I know we can set timeout using resource manager at schema level. But I want to set timeout to a specific query inside a procedure and catch the exception. lets say i want to stop query execution for specific query after 15 secs. Is there any way for this? Or any timeout exception available? I am using Oracle Db 12.2. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to catch the exception in PL/SQL or in the application? There's an indirect way to stop a query or procedure with the `ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL` command, but that command raises the exception `ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation` that cannot be caught by PL/SQL.

Comment: @JonHeller i need to catch exception in PL/SQL. Also i am using Oracle 12.2 Db while i think ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL command introduce in Oracle 18c.

Comment: There's no way to catch the exception in the same PL/SQL block, you'd probably need to do something like Littlefoot's solution and use an asynchronous scheduler job and check the status. The `ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL` command supposedly works in 12.2, although it's undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no such thing.

However, see if this helps:

- instead of running the procedure itself, **schedule** it (using `dbms_scheduler`)
- then, find the job by querying `dba_scheduler_running_jobs`
- finally, if you think it runs too long, *kill* it (using `dbms_scheduler.stop_job`)

Yes, I know - you're talking about a query within a procedure. It makes things more complex as the rest of the procedure should wait for that particular query (now transformed to job) to finish.

---

Though, if it were a loop, you could set a timer and check it in every loop iteration and then exit the loop if it runs longer than 15 seconds. Maybe you can make that query to use condition you'd put into e.g. cursor FOR loop's `where` clause ...

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. No i cannot make it schedule job. Actually my scenario is that there are some complex read data procedures which are based upon some complex sql queries and there are no loop involve. These procedures call include different input parameters from front end. I just want to put time limit only on some procedures that if that time exceeds then cancel query execution, raise exception and show that exception on front end rather than end user waits for minutes.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, as I said, I don't know whether anything like what you need exists in Oracle. Hopefully, someone else will able to assist.